# Using Parsedown in Laravel 5.6.3

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to use [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/) in Laravel 5.6.3. As far as I can tell, Composer packages are autoloaded into Laravel, so I should be able to do something like this:

```
{{ Parsedown('## Hello World!') }}
```

But when I try that, I get:

> Call to undefined function Parsedown().

So I tried to create an object of Parsedown with the following:

```
{{ $parsedown = new \Parsedown() }}
```

But then I get

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

At first I thought it was something to do with Laravel's autoloader, but when I request something from vlucas/dotenv I get the results I expect:

`<p>{{ getenv('APP_NAME') }}</p>` outputs `Laravel`.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I can't find anything in the Laravel docs to help me out either.

---

### Edit

The answer by @AlexeyMezenin is correct, and it answers my original question. However it did not allow my markdown to be rendered. The following two lines are correct and allow markdown to be rendered:

```
@php($parsedown = new Parsedown())
<?= $parsedown->text('Hello _Parsedown_!'); ?>
```

It seems that the blade templating engine is having issues with echoing out parsedown. This edit has been added to help other users having the same problem as myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{}}` will be rendered to `echo` by Blade engine. So, so change this:

```
{{ $parsedown = new \Parsedown() }}
```

To:

```
@php($parsedown = new \Parsedown())
```

Or:

```
@php
    $parsedown = new \Parsedown();
@endphp
```

Or:

```
<?php $parsedown = new \Parsedown(); ?>
```

Comment: We're one step closer! I'm now getting ```Function name must be a string```.

Comment: @mohnjatthews I don't think the error is related to the code you've shown. It means you've fixed the error and now you need to fix the next error not related to the first one.

Comment: Yes, you are right @AlexeyMezenin. This error is not occur after this changes!

Comment: Good point @AlexeyMezenin. I'll work on fixing this new error, and mark your answer as correct once I'm allowed (in 4 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed `parsedown/laravel` using composer? That should solve your problem, as given in the documentation at https://github.com/parsedown/laravel

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Nico. However, Laravel 5.6.3 already comes pre-packaged with Parsedown ([seen here](https://ibb.co/dwCzLx)).

Comment: Are you sure that the packages `parsedown/laravel` and `erusev/parsedown` are the same? I'd say that these are two completely independent projects - the first one providing integration for Parsedown into Laravel projects (and depending on the second one), the second one just providing Parsedown itself...

Comment: From what I can tell the difference between the two packages is that `parsedown/laravel` allows one to use Parsedown within a blade template, whereas the `erusev/parsedown` package does not. It seems odd that Laravel would come packaged with the standalone version, and not the one specifically intended for use with Laravel. Thank you for point that out to me.